# while i use associated type synonym, ghc responds Could not deduce oo from the context xx

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

I refactor my code by using type Families, below is a typeclass used in project.

```
class HeukaryaGene (d :: *) where
  type TypeGeneStr d :: *
  type TypeGeneRep d :: *
  lexByArrow   :: TypeGeneStr d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  geneTypeRep  :: d -> TypeGeneRep d
  geneTypeRepArgs :: TypeGeneRep d -> [TypeGeneRep d]
  showGeneTypeRep :: TypeGeneRep d -> TypeGeneStr d
  showExpandTypeArgs :: d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  showExpandTypeArgs dynam = lexByArrow typo
    where
    typo = showGeneTypeRep $ geneTypeRep dynam :: TypeGeneStr d
```

but ghc always complain a lot of the same things:

```
Could not deduce (TypeGeneStr d ~ TypeGeneStr d2)
from the context (HeukaryaGene d)
  bound by the class declaration for `HeukaryaGene'
  at AI/Heukarya/Gene.hs:(22,1)-(42,63)
NB: `TypeGeneStr' is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable `d2' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: [TypeGeneStr d]
  Actual type: [TypeGeneStr d2]
In the return type of a call of `lexByArrow'
In the expression: lexByArrow typo
In an equation for `showExpandTypeArgs':
    showExpandTypeArgs dynam
      = lexByArrow typo
      where
          typo = showGeneTypeRep $ geneTypeRep dynam :: TypeGeneStr d
```

i wonder what did i misunderstand

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926579/incomprehensible-error-message-with-type-families?rq=1 and my answer to that question.

Comment: That's better than what I was just typing.

Comment: Despite my answer to this question, I'd like to endorse kosmikus's answer too.

Comment: according to your solution, I find an elegant solution!

Comment: I suppose you meant to ping Antal or kosmikus?

Comment: to kosmikus actually. I'll read Antal's answer later

Answer (score 4):

You can't go from a type family such as `TypeGeneStr d` back to the original type `d`.  When GHC says "NB: `` `TypeGeneStr' `` is a type function, and may not be injective", this is what it's telling you: just knowing that `TypeGeneStr d ~ TypeGeneStr d'` does not imply that `d ~ d'` (where `~` is type equality).

Thus, when you have a type class function which only has type synonyms in its name and never refers to the original argument, you'll never be able to call it—and this describes every function in your type class except `geneTypeRep` and the unimplementable `showExpandTypeArgs`.  The reason this fails is that GHC can't figure out which instance of the type class to use.  Consider what happens if I allow `TypeGeneStr` and/or `TypeGeneRep` to collide, as in the following example:

```
class HeukaryaGene Int where
  type TypeGeneStr Int = String
  type TypeGeneRep Int = ()
  showGeneTypeRep () = "Int"

class HeukaryaGene Bool where
  type TypeGeneStr Bool = String
  type TypeGeneRep Bool = ()
  showGeneTypeRep () = "Bool"
```

Then should `showGeneTypeRep ()` be `"Int"` or `"Bool"`?  Or should it even be a `String`?  What if I have

```
class HeukaryaGene () where
  type TypeGeneStr () = ()
  type TypeGeneRep () = ()
  showGeneTypeRep () = ()
```

Then `showGeneTypeRep ()` could be `()`, too.  This is biting you in your definition of `showExpandTypeArgs`: inside `typo`, while GHC can correctly determine that `dynam :: d` and thus `geneTypeRep dynam :: TypeGeneRep d`, it doesn't know which `showGeneTypeRep :: TypeGeneRep d -> TypeGeneStr d` to pick.  And your call of `lexByArrow` suffers from a similar problem: all GHC knows is that `typo :: TypeGeneStr d'` for some `d'`, and it doesn't know which version of `lexByArrow :: TypeGeneStr d' -> [TypeGeneStr d']` to pick (it does know that `TypeGeneRep d ~ TypeGeneRep d'`, but that's not enough to decide).

On my GHC (7.4.2), I'm also getting an error that the `d` in your type signature for `Typo` isn't the same as the `d` in the type class head, but just deleting that type signature (obviously) doesn't get things to type check.

(I should say: The error messages you're getting here are definitely confusing, as they don't make it clear what's going on and why there's an error.)

---

The simplest fix I can think of for this is to include a dummy `d` parameter for all your functions that don't take one.  You would never analyze that parameter; it's just used to coax instance selection along.  At the call site, you could use `undefined :: d` for some concrete type `d`.  That would look like this:

```
class HeukaryaGene (d :: *) where
  type TypeGeneStr d :: *
  type TypeGeneRep d :: *
  lexByArrow   :: d -> TypeGeneStr d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  geneTypeRep  :: d -> TypeGeneRep d
  geneTypeRepArgs :: d -> TypeGeneRep d -> [TypeGeneRep d]
  showGeneTypeRep :: d -> TypeGeneRep d -> TypeGeneStr d
  showExpandTypeArgs :: d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  showExpandTypeArgs dynam = lexByArrow dynam typo
    where
    typo = showGeneTypeRep dynam $ geneTypeRep dynam
```

---

If you don't like that, the least-invasive fix I can think of for this is to go from type families to data families.  Data families are like type families, except you use the keyword `data` and they define brand new data types.  This is important: just like ordinary data constructions, data families *are* generative, and thus injective.  (Each instantiation of a data family generates a brand new type.)  That would look like this:

```
class HeukaryaGene (d :: *) where
  data TypeGeneStr d :: *
  data TypeGeneRep d :: *
  lexByArrow   :: TypeGeneStr d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  geneTypeRep  :: d -> TypeGeneRep d
  geneTypeRepArgs :: TypeGeneRep d -> [TypeGeneRep d]
  showGeneTypeRep :: TypeGeneRep d -> TypeGeneStr d
  showExpandTypeArgs :: d -> [TypeGeneStr d]
  showExpandTypeArgs dynam = lexByArrow typo
    where
    typo = showGeneTypeRep $ geneTypeRep dynam
```

The only changes I made were changing `type` to `data` and deleting your type signature for `typo`.  The catch of this version is that to instantiate `HeukaryaGene` now, you have to write something like

```
instance HeukaryaGene Int where
  -- You can instantiate data families with newtypes, too.
  newtype TypeGeneStr Int = TGSInt String
  data    TypeGeneRep Int = TGRInt
  showGeneTypeRep TGRInt = TGSInt "Int"
```

That is, there's potentially a lot of (un)wrapping to do.  But this will work.

You could also use functional dependencies here, but you'd essentially be replicating this solution and its drawbacks; the idea is that you'd have `class HeukaryaGene d tgs tgr | d -> tgs tgr, tgs -> d, tgr -> d`, so that knowing any one of `d`, `tgs`, or `tgr` is enough to infer the other two.  This looks good, but means any given type can only be used once as a gene-string or gene-rep type, and thus has essentially the same drawbacks as the data family version above.

---

Another solution would be, if you never call `lexByArrow` or `showGeneTypeRep` outside of `showExpandTypeArgs`, to remove them from the type class and let the user implement `showExpandTypeArgs` how they may.  That doesn't help with `geneTypeRepArgs`, though, which would just have to go

---

And the last solution would be to not use type classes, but to handle the dictionaries yourself.  This would be a pretty radical redesign (although not necessarily a bad one), but if you really want type synonyms for `TypeGeneStr` and `TypeGeneRep`, it's the only way I can think of.  That would look like this:

```
data HeukaryaGene d tgs tgr =
  HeukaryaGene { lexByArrow      :: tgs -> [tgs]
               , geneTypeRep     :: d -> tgr
               , geneTypeRepArgs :: tgr -> [tgr]
               , showGeneTypeRep :: tgr -> tgs }

showExpandTypeArgs :: d -> [tgs]
showExpandTypeArgs dynam = lexByArrow typo
  where typo = showGeneTypeRep $ geneTypeRep dynam
```

Then, functions that previously had the type `HeukaryaGene d => t` would have the type `HeukaryaGene d tgs tr -> t`.  Using `-XRecordWildCards` (and as-patterns) would help here, allowing you to write

```
getTypeRepArgs HeukaryaGene{..} = geneTypeRepArgs . geneTypeRep
```

If you wanted some dictionaries to have a different implementation of `showExpandTypeArgs`, you'd have to structure things slightly differently:

```
data HeukaryaGene d tgs tgr =
  HeukaryaGene { lexByArrow         :: tgs -> [tgs]
               , geneTypeRep        :: d -> tgr
               , geneTypeRepArgs    :: tgr -> [tgr]
               , showGeneTypeRep    :: tgr -> tgs
               , showExpandTypeArgs :: d -> [tgs] }

showExpandTypeArgsDefault :: HeukaryaGene d tgs tgr -> d -> [tgs]
showExpandTypeArgsDefault HeukaryaGene{..} dynam = lexByArrow typo
  where typo = showGeneTypeRep $ geneTypeRep dynam
```

Then, you would tie the knot during initialization:

```
hgInt :: HeukaryaGene Int String ()
hgInt = HeukaryaGene { lexByArrow         = words
                     , geneTypeRep        = const ()
                     , geneTypeRepArgs    = const []
                     , showGeneTypeRep    = const "Int"
                     , showExpandTypeArgs = showExpandTypeArgsDefault hgInt }
```

In fact, in this solution, `d` might be superfluous in `geneTypeRep`, and thus `showExpandTypeArgs`, and thus `HeukaryaGene` itself: if, like in `Typeable`, you were just using `d` to pick the type class, then you don't need that here.  But that would depend on your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

I find this elegant solution according to : [Incomprehensible error message with type families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926579/incomprehensible-error-message-with-type-families?rq=1)

typeclass definition:

```
class (
  UnTypeGeneStr (TypeGeneStr d) ~ d, UnTypeGeneRep (TypeGeneRep d) ~ d
  ) => HeukaryaGene d where
  type TypeGeneStr d :: *
  type TypeGeneRep d :: *
  type UnTypeGeneStr o :: *
  type UnTypeGeneRep o :: *
```

instance definition:

```
instance HeukaryaGene Dynamic where
  type TypeGeneStr Dynamic = String
  type TypeGeneRep Dynamic = TypeRep
  type UnTypeGeneStr String  = Dynamic
  type UnTypeGeneRep TypeRep = Dynamic
```

Thanks for everyone's help!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but GHC 8.0 added support for [injective type synonyms](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/InjectiveTypeFamilies). If you enable `TypeFamilyDependencies`, your example should work with something like:

```
class HeukaryaGene d where
  type TypeGeneStr d = s | s -> d
  type TypeGeneRep d = r | r -> d
  ...
```