# Binding together data, types and functions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

I want to model a large tree (or forest) of some regular structure - tree can be decomposed to small tree (the irregular part) and (i.e.) large list of params, each of them with each of nodes make a node of big tree.

So, I want a data structure, where each node in a tree is representing many nodes. And real node is of type (node,param).

For algorithms that work on this kind of trees type of that param does not mattter. They are just placeholders. But some data should be possible to extract from the plain param or combination of node and param, and all possible params should be iterable. All that kinds of data is known apriori, they reflect semantic of that tree.

So, actual type, semantics and stuff of param is up to implementation of tree.

I model it in C++ using nested typedefs for params type, fixed method names for all kind of stuff that should be available to algorithm (this two together making a concept) and templates for algorithm itself.

I.e. if I want to associate with each node of big tree an integer, I would provide a function `int data(const node& n, const param& p)`, where `param` is available as nested typedef, and algorithm could get list of all available params, and call `data` with nodes of interest and each of params

---

I have some plain data type, i.e. tree data, like this

```
data Tree = Node [Tree] | Leaf
```

Now I want to package up:

- concrete tree
- some type
- some values of that type
- some functions operating on (that concrete) tree nodes and (that) values

So one can write some function that use this packaged up types and functions, like, generic way.

How to achieve that?

---

With type families I came to

```
class PackagedUp t where
  type Value t

  tree :: Tree t
  values :: [Value t]
  f :: Tree t -> Value t -> Int
```

`Tree` now become `Tree t` because type families want type of their members to depend on typeclass argument.

Also, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16927632/1227578 type families to deal with injectivity will be needed.

With this I can

```
instance PackagedUp MyTree where
  type Value MyTree = (Int,Int)
  tree = Leaf
  values = [(0,0),(1,1)]
  f t v = fst v
```

And how to write such a function now? I.e. a function that will take root of a tree, all of values and make a `[Int]` of all `f tree value`.

Comment: Your definition of `Tree` is not what you want, and I'm pretty sure you don't need to go as far as type families to solve your problem. To give an useful answer, however, we need to know what you want `f` to do, as that is not very clear from the code.

Comment: Actually I want to model certain kind of a game tree, I'll explain in question. I already did that in C++, and now trying to port that to Haskell. Don't ask why)

Comment: I think you are complicating things. Just make a module with the things you want to bundle.

Comment: @augustss I'm trying to make a generic data structure and algorithm for that. Maybe it's too complicated solution, or even maybe I should not bother memory for huge trees in haskell, but certainly I want a way to handle generic things.

Comment: Before you attempt to generalize using a class, try a more specific implementation.  And try generalizing with type parameters and functions rather than a class.

Comment: @augustss you just gave me an idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your tree type should be defined like this:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] | Leaf
```

The type above is polymorphic. As far as semantics go that resembles what we would call a generic type in OO parlance (in C# or Java we might write `Tree<A>` instead). A node of a `Tree a` holds a value of type `a` and a list of subtrees.

Next, we come to `PackagedUp`. Classes in Haskell have little to do with the OO concept of the same name; they are not meant to package data and behaviour together. Things are actually much simpler: all you need to do is defining the appropriate functions for your tree type

```
getRoot :: Tree a -> Maybe a
getRoot Leaf       = Nothing
getRoot (Node x _) = Just x
```

(Returning `Maybe a` is a simple way to handle failure with type safety. Think of the `Nothing` value as a polite cousin of `null` that doesn't explode with null reference exceptions.)

One thing that type classes are good at is in expressing data structure algorithm interfaces such as the ones you allude to. One of the most common classes is `Functor`, which provides a general interface for mapping over data structures.

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f Leaf        = Leaf
    fmap f (Node x ts) = Node (f x) (fmap f ts)
```

`fmap` has the following polymorphic type:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

With your tree, it specialises to

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

and with lists (as in `fmap f ts`) it becomes

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Finally, the [`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.2.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) module provides a data structure which looks a lot like what you want to define.

Comment: Thing I want is interface. And the nearest thing to that is concepts in c++, which I used, and type classes in haskell.

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov You would want an interface if there were several data types you wanted to abstract from. `Functor` is an interface in that sense, as `fmap` works with trees and lists and tons of other data structures. In your case, however, you have just a single data type, and so you don't need a type class to abstract from it. The polymorphism of the functions which take or return a `Tree a` is enough. For instance, the `getRoot` I defined above will work with trees containing elements of any type.

Comment: I've just realised that functions can be members of `data`, so I can split implementation and calling without `class`!

Comment: While it's not in `base`, `Tree` looks like it would be a good candidate to be a [`Comonad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:Comonad). `getRoot` would then be called `extract`. In fact, the `Tree` defined looks pretty similar to a [`Cofree []`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.7.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html#t:Cofree).

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov Trying to write Haskell as if it was an OO language leads only to headache in the vast majority of cases. The coupling problem does not manifest in Haskell in the same way that it does in OOP, and so the solutions are also different. If you want freedom to change the implementation, most of the time all you need to do is to put your functions in a module and export only the functions you want in the public API. That is what augustss meant when he mentioned modules.

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov P.S.: About your remark on functions in data types: well spotted! In fact, in the rare cases we actually want to approximate objects in Haskell (for instance, when you really need something like an heterogeneous list of upcast values. Again, surely not in your case!) doing that tends to be better than using type classes. That approach is often referred to as "records of functions".