# Inverting a Type Family

Tags: haskell, type-families

I've got a "linear" type family, i.e. of the form

```
type family Foo a
type instance Foo T1 = T2
type instance Foo T2 = T3
...
type instance Foo T9 = T10
```

In my particualr use-case, it is very convenient to define the "reverse" family `FooRev` and then enforce the constraint `(FooRev (Foo x) ~ x)`:

```
type family FooRev a
type instance FooRev T10 = T9
type instance FooRev T9 = T8
...
type instance FooRev T2 = T1
```

The reverse family allows GHC to infer many types that would otherwise be ambiguous due to non-injectivity. It is essentially the same idea that was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16927632/925978). This solution works pretty well, but it is annoying, programatic, and error-prone to have to define a "reverse" type family by listing out all the cases. Is there a more generic way to define the reverse of a linear family such as `Foo`?

Comment: Maybe you could use `data` families instead somehow, which are known injective.  Not sure if it fits your problem.

Comment: Metaprogramming (i.e. Template Haskell) might generate both, keeping your code DRY if that's your concern. Otherwise, you could define a type-level association list, a type level lookup, a type level `map swap`, and derive both type families from the list.

Comment: @luqui I just saw that before posting, but as far as I know, that's not really what I need. In my case, the `Ti` are all type `Bar a b c` where the type parameters change. That won't fit into a data family, will it?

Comment: @chi Perhaps you could demonstrate one of those ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to give @chi's idea try, and but I came up with something a little simpler in the end.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

type family NextElt (a :: *) (xs :: [*]) where
  NextElt a (a ': b ': cs) = b
  NextElt a (b ': c ': cs) = NextElt a (c ': cs)

type family PrevElt (a :: *) (xs :: [*]) :: * where
  PrevElt a (b ': a ': xs) = b
  PrevElt a (b ': c ': xs) = PrevElt a (c ': xs)

data T1
data T2
data T3
type TSeq = '[T1, T2, T3]

type NextRp a = NextElt a TSeq
type PrevRp a = PrevElt a TSeq
```

Using a type list to represent the linear sequence of types allows me to express the relationship without writing each type twice (which is necessary using type family instances or instances of a class). The type families above uses a sliding-window approach to search for an element in a list with a previous or next element. These type families are generic (and can be extended to work for non-`*` kinds using [Data.Type.Equality](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html).)

Answer (score 5):

I think `FunctionalDependencies` should be the best solution for your case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Foo a b | a -> b, b -> a
instance Foo T1 T2
instance Foo T2 T3
...
```

Now each `b` can be inferred from an `a` and vice versa.